# Wisdom query using Spring JpaRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Suggest, I have next structure of objects:

```
class MovieWrapper {
    private Movie movie;
}
class Movie {
    private User user;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
}
```

and I want to query from repository only first occurrence of MovieWrapper by User Id and where status is Active or Pending:

```
@Repository
public interface MovieWrapperRepository extends JpaRepository<MovieWrapper, Long> {
    MovieWrapper findFirstByMovieUserIdAndMovieStatusActiveOrMovieStatusPending(Long userId);
}
```

How to do it in correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 'custom' object from the repo method you should use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) (interface-base projection is preferable IMO).

To implement complex method you can build its query yourself, for example:

```java
public interface MovieRepo extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {
    Query("select m as movie from Movie m where m.user.id = ?1 and (m.status = 'ACTIVE' or m.status = 'PENDING')")
    List<MovieProjection> findActiveOrPending(Long userId, Status status);
}
```

Where `MovieProjection` is a simple interface:

```java
public interface MovieProjection {
    Movie getMovie();
}
```

Note to the alias `m as movie` in the query, it's recommended to use with projections to avoid some errors.

**UPDATED**

If you need only one records you can use a trick with `Pageable`:

```java
public interface MovieRepo extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long> {
    Query("select m as movie from Movie m where m.user.id = ?1 and (m.status = 'ACTIVE' or m.status = 'PENDING')")
    List<MovieProjection> findAllActiveOrPending(Long userId, Status status, Pageable pageable);

    default Optional<MovieProjection> getFirstOne(Long userId, Status status) {
        return findAllActiveOrPending(userId, status, PageRequest.of(0, 1)).stream().findAny();
    }
}
```

Here we take first page with one record (`PageRequest.of(0, 1)` - see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-))

Comment: Yes, it works fine with Query, but I thought whether to use exist, not select all movies and than check that size >0. I want to optimize it.

Comment: Я тебя не понял. Что ты имеешь в виду?

Comment: I mean how just to check that at least one record exist in table. It is not optimal to query all available records to know that at least one record exist. Does it make sense?

Comment: Первую с какого конца? )

Comment: it doesn't matter)